# Other than downvoting, how can I make someone understand an answer is terrible?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

Answer in question (well that's awkward):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031761/438992

I'm specifically *not* asking for a doggie-pile, but rather a way to extend the discussion beyond question comments and chat, including both the OP, who clearly needs some help, and the answerer in question, who I believe is doing a *serious* disservice to the OP beyond just being wrong.

In this case, I want a sort of mix between codereview.se and chat.

Is there any sort of existing mechanism beyond a downvote, exasperation, and a delete vote?

Comment: That's really it.  And commenting.  Long, glorious comments, leading to long, glorious comment trails.

Comment: Add the "correct" answer. Given that you know how the current answer is flawed/terrible, you surely can add something better. If that's more highly upvoted in the end, well, point proven. P.s. the answer you link to does not necessarily warrant a delete vote IMO. A downvote, yes.

Comment: @Bart: Unfortunately, knowing whether an answer is bad/wrong doesn't always mean knowing what the right answer is.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Not always, so not an answer, but in this particular case I have a sneaking suspicion Dave would do a decent job.

Comment: @Bart Not from my tablet, unfortunately ;) But IMO deleting an answer that (a) doesn't address either the asked, or implied, question, and (b) is Just Plain Wrong makes SO a better place, particularly since it's difficult to have a reasonable, visible discussion highlighting how wrong it is (IMO).

Comment: If answer is bad, downvote. Comment is optional, but might help the answerer and make him improve the answer. If the answer is plain terrible and misleading, delete. That's the reason we have such power in the first place. :)

Comment: Some of us 20k types have fixed this problem for you. When answers are sufficiently awful, we treat then as 'not an' and vote to delete.

Comment: @DaveNewton All else failing, you could always call their mom. ;)

Comment: @Bart I don't have the rep for that yet, is that a 100k privilege?

Comment: @Dave Newton: If it is, I don't have it yet.

Comment: (Insert any of various "yo momma's rep is so low..." jokes here.)

Answer (score 3):

In spite of the literal text of the 'not an answer' mod flag, it has become the practice of 10 and 20k users to delete truly awful answers. If we didn't have this habit before, we certainly developed it in working the 'late answers' and 'very low quality' post queues.

In other words, while the flag (and, perhaps, by implication deletion) talks about things that aren't even remotely an answer (thanks, me-too, random comments), we delete things that are just crap.

In the case you have highlighted, that process worked as ?intended?. If the management didn't like this behavior of ours, they would surely have let us know some time ago.

If you don't have that much rep, you can flag 'very low quality' with a clear conscience.

Comment: Worth noting: vote to undelete and flag to undelete are always available if the answer is really worth saving.